I am trying to fill missing data, and i used the "fillna" function but it returned as an error, please can I be clearified?
/var/folders/d4/4m3wk25x6wq2nmkr7h73pdv00000gn/T/ipykernel_58212/1139554158.py:1: FutureWarning: Setting an item of incompatible dtype is deprecated and will raise in a future error of pandas. Value '0%' has dtype incompatible with float64, please explicitly cast to a compatible dtype first.
fill_data = df.fillna("0%", inplace=True)

To make up for missing details.

seems you have to convert values to float and then apply fillna. Can you share the code please?

You tried to put the string value “0%” in a floating point column.
That won’t work, don’t do it.
Prefer to supply the numeric value 0 instead.
